# How to get changes from a branch that I have been merging to it?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase, git-workflow

We are a team where we branch off from a `WorkInProgress` branch, to our own branch and all our work gets "dumped" into `WorkInProgress`.

When a dev is done with some work/feature, they commit to their branch and push to their remote. Then, they do "Pull Request" remotely from their branch to the remote `WorkInProgress`.

We have been doing this for a long time. Today, we want to "sync". So for example myself, I want to get all the developers' work from `WorkInProgress` branch, into my branch.

Would Git know the changes that are common (`WorkInProgress` has commits from my branch already) and exclude them when "merging back" to my branch?

How do I "update" my branch properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the latest version of the local `WorkInProgress` branch (`git fetch origin WorkInProgress:WorkInProgress`)
2. Checkout your own branch (`git checkout OwnBranch`)
3. Merge the `WorkInProgress` branch into your own branch (`git merge WorkInProgress`), you may have to resolve conflicts.

When you later make the pull request to merge your branch back in, git will correctly identify where to start comparing the branches from and which commits it needs to put in.

Comment: When I do step 3), will Git know the common commits and just work it out? (Common commits means the ones that I merged from my branch to WorkInProgress in the past)

Comment: Yes, when git does a merge it goes back along both branches and locates the "merge-base". This has nothing to do with when and where the branches where created and just their topology. The merge base is simply the closest common ancestor they have.
If you do 3 commits on your own branch (A,B,C) and then merge them into `WorkInProgress` creating a merge commit D then the commit C exist on both branches and is the merge base, so only the commits after C are merged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have common commits in two branches then git will take care of it and you would not need to worry about the changes getting duplicated.

To update your branch from `WorkInProgress` branch, you just need to simply run the `git pull` command to merge the changes from remote `WorkInProgress` to your own branch.